# Plotting two barplots together in R (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to do a barplot of this dataset

```
           df <- data.frame(Modelos=c("Model 1", "Model 2"),            
          MSE_test=c(123293931,23231231),MSE_train=c(100001,2292894))
```

I want to do a barplot of this to compare the values of each model in train and test. I think on that code but this doesn't do what I want.

```
           ggplot(df, aes(x=Modelos,y=MSE_test, fill = MSE_train)) + 
          geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

I want each Model in the x axis and for each model one bar to test and the other to train. I hope to be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reshape the data first with reshape2 or tidyverse packages:

```
library(reshape2)

df <- df %>% 
    melt(id = "Modelos")
```

or

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>%
    gather(variable, value, - Modelos)
```

then plot:

```
 ggplot(df, aes(Modelos, value)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = variable),stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    scale_y_log10()
```